# XSLT/XPATH How to concatenate two strings containing Hebrew characters in a left to right direction?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to concatenate two strings containing Hebrew character in XSLT/XPATH (NOT XSL-FO), however, when I try "concat(string A, String B), the output I'm getting is String B + String A.

I guess this is probably because of the fact that Hebrew characters have a right to left direction. However, what can I do in order to get String A + String B in the output? The output file I need to produce is a text file (neither XML nor HTML).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Update: Here is an example:

example: יוסף 
          בניון

then concat(stringA,stringB) gets me this: יוסףבניון instead of בניוןיוסף

Also, there's no guarantee that stringA and stringB will always contain Hebrew characters, so concat(stringB, stringA) would not work for me.

Comment: What about if try concat(string B, String A) ?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example -see: [mcve].

Comment: Hi Michael. Here is an example: <stringA>יוסף</stringA>
<stringB>בניון</stringB>  then concat(stringA,stringB) gets me this: יוסףבניון instead of בניוןיוסף

Comment: @Raj: The problem is that string A and string B could also contain characters in English. Unfortunately, there's no guarantee it will always be in Hebrew.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <stringA>יוסף</stringA>
> <stringB>בניון</stringB>
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> concat(stringA,stringB)
> ```
>
> gets me this:
>
> ```
> יוסףבניון
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> בניוןיוסף
> ```

The result that you get **is** the correct result: `stringA` **is** **before** `stringB`.

Because the characters are RTL, the entire block is **displayed** from right-to-left (as one would expect). However, the order of the individual characters in the underlying string (as well as in the resulting text file) is:

```
י
ו
ס
ף
ב
נ
י
ו
ן
```

You can verify this by looking at the hex dump of the file.

Comment: Hi Michael,thanks for confirming this. As I mentioned in my original question, I was guessing the output I was seeing was correct due to the characters being RTL. Is there a way to force the engine to concatenate the strings using a LTR direction?

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the point. The string themselves have no direction. A string is a sequence of characters - and the `concat()` function will simply append the second string to the first one, with no regard to which characters any of the strings contain. The RTL property of the characters only comes into play when the string is being displayed on screen.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks a lot!